# cycle for in template and "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error when compiling with jade

Tags: node.js, mongoose, pug

So this is the search function for the get route /users/search:

```
// peopleRoutes.js:25:16
exports.search = function (req, res) {
    var term = req.query.term;
    User.find({$or: [
            {username:  {$in: [term]}},
            {bio:       {$in: [term]}},
            {location:  {$in: [term]}}  
        ]}, function (err, users) {
                var fn = jade.compileFile('path/to/template.jade'), {});
                var html = fn(users);
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", 'text/html');
                res.send(html);
                res.end();
    }).sort({username: 'asc'});
};
```

This is the template I want to retrieve:

```
ul.list-group(id='main-list')
    for user in users
        li.list-group-item
            div.col-md-3.no-padd-l
                img(src= user.gravatarUrl, alt='avatar')
                div= user.location
            div.col-md-9.no-padd-r
                div.strong= user.username
                div= user.bio
```

I continue to receive the following error message:

```
c:\...\node_modules\jade\lib\runtime.js:240
  throw err;
        ^
TypeError: c:\.../path/to/template.jade:2
    1| ul.list-group(id='main-list')
  > 2|  - for user in users
    3|          li.list-group-item
    4|                  div.col-md-3.no-padd-l
    5|                          img(src= user.gravatarUrl, alt='avatar')

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (c:\...\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:17:31)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (c:\...\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:114:4)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (c:\...\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:218:8), <anonymous>:120:22)
    at res (c:\...\node_modules\jade\lib\index.js:219:38)
    at Query.<anonymous> (c:\...\people\peopleRoutes.js:25:16)
    at c:\...\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:177:19
    at c:\...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

I read that there is a solution to get rid of the "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" error message by adding a blank line at the end of the .jade template but it doesn't work for me. Any idea on what can cause this error? The User.find query seems to return the correct values...

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use:

```
var html = fn(users: users);
```

instead of

```
var html = fn(users);
```

Comment: Also, why aren't you using [`res.render()`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#res.render) instead of compiling the template for each request?